# Inconsistent reputation scores for an individual

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The reputation scores for *[Lauren](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/11387/lauren)* (as seen in part below) seem inconsistent.  For example, "1 ANSWER" and "1 QUESTION" appear at left, but at right <s>answers to at least four questions are denoted</s> other stuff appears.  Just out of curiosity, is this a database bug, or some kind of feature?

[image: Lauren rep snip]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cases of *+2 reputation* come from getting suggested edits to posts approved. These answers are not actually Lauren's, merely ones she edited.

Comment: It's obvious now you've explained it; previously I was unaware of points for having a suggested edit approved.  Does that cut off at >100 rep?  Lauren has [made 356 edits](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/11387/lauren?tab=activity) but has rep < 2000 which allows [Edit other people’s posts](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation); have all 356 of those edits been individually approved?

Comment: Normally, that would be the case. However, Lauren happens to be a member of the Stack Exchange CHAOS team, and for a brief time, they were granted full editing privileges to allow them to edit titles, which was one of their first projects. Reputation from suggested edits caps at a maximum of 500 approved edits or the user attaining 2000 rep, whichever comes first.